# REST Endpoint with more then one identifier

Tags: api, rest, semantics, endpoint, identifier

I have this case where i need to get an item that can be identified by more the one id. And the consumer should be able to decide which one they use.

```
/product/{productId}
/product/{gtin}
/product/{pzn}
```

If i do it like displayed above, it is not clear anymore what ID the consumer is using.

My solution so far:

```
/product/productId/{productId}
/product/gtin/{gtin}
/product/pzn/{pzn}
```

What is the best practice to deal with this kind of variety?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best practice to deal with this kind of variety?

Anything that ensures your identifiers aren't ambiguous is *fine*.

On the web, what you'll see commonly is the use of key/value pairs in the query string, because that is natively supported by HTML

```
/product?productId={productId}
/product?gtin={gtin}
/product?pzn={pzn}
```

If you don't care about HTML support, but still want to be able to take advantage of general purpose tooling, then look into [URI Templates](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570) which allow you to communicate other URI construction recipes.

```
/product/productId/{productId}
/product?productId={productId}
```

Either of these alternatives are *fine*.  The latter spelling works better with HTML forms, the former spelling works better with [relative resolution](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-5.2).

How to choose? since the machines don't care, prioritize some group of humans impacted by the choice (operators reading logs, writers producing documentation, consumers looking at a browser history), and choose the spelling that best suits their needs.